# grep not working with BOM

Tags: bash, byte-order-mark

I am trying to `grep` a string from a file but grep returns nothing (even though the string is present in the file). It turned out that the file starts with a `ÿþ` mark. If I remove it manually then grep works. How do I make grep work without manually removing the BOM?

Comment: Post an example of the file and the `grep` command, please.

Comment: The presence of the BOM sounds like an error; I'm not sure why removing it *isn't* the solution.

Comment: @anubhava - That questioner was asking how to find files with a BOM, not how to find text within such files.

Comment: @Benj: That's not the sense I get from OP's first statement `I am trying to grep a string from a file but grep returns nothing`.

Comment: @anubhava - I'm not referring to this question, I'm referring to the one you said it was a dupe of.

Comment: @Benj: Accepted answer there has `sed '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//'` which should be good enough to tell OP how to `grep`

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
strings <file> | grep <pattern>
```

Alternatively check the man page of your `grep` command.  What's actually happening is that `grep` is looking at the first few bytes of your file and deciding that it's a binary file and therefore not searchable.  You can override this with:

```
--binary-files=text
```

Comment: Caveat: Files may be coded in UTF-16 (-received from Windows system?). Then grep (and other methods) will fail on multi-character ascii patterns even if the BOM is removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use cat with the -v (visible) option:

```
cat -v file | grep pattern
```